# How to enforce css style over existing classes (specially in Bootrstap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When I want to apply a certain style to a div (specially using bootstrap  3), I create my own class like this:

```
.myClass {
   width: 30%;
   padding-right: 0px;
}

<div class="myClass"></div>
```

But sometimes the div style is overwritten by the bootstrap classes or another inherited properties (I don't understand completely the inheritance in CSS3), but if I apply directly in the div:

```
<div style="width: 30%;padding-right: 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: You can do it with important `padding-right: 0px !important;` if you must. But people don't like this solution much.

Comment: You can use [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get the desired styles working.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to force CSS on an element in this case :

1. **You have you custom CSS located in a local `.css` file** : put the `<link>` tag for this custom stylesheet *after* the Bootstrap css file.
2. Set the CSS rule `!important` after each properties so they will get an extra authority upon others

Answer (score 0):

CSS inheritance 
`.myClass` is less than `div.myClass` which is less than `body div.myClass`.

The Bootstrap is using usually more than one identifier. Like `.ourClass.theirClass.yourClass` which is hard to overwrite. Inspect your element in your browser to see the inheritance and try to overwrite it the css way before using any `!important` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The last rule defining a style of the element will be aplied to it.
So if you have various stylesheets in your page, the order of the files should be in the order you want them to be applied. example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="secondStyle.css">
```

Every style rule(not an entire block) that is written in the second file will be the definitive one in the website.

the same rule apllies within files, for example:

```
.ClassOne {
    color: red;
}

... othes styling ...

.classOne {
    color: Black;
}
```

In this case the color in the browser will be Black because it was the last one and it overwrites the first one.

There is another rule that can affect styling - The more specific rule will be the definitive one, example:

```
.one .two .three {
    color: red;
}

.two .three {
    color: blue;
}

.one .three {
    color: green;
}

<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
            some text
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:** In which color will the text show?
**Answer:** red.
Why? because in the case above, we call the .three element in a more specific way when we declared the red color.
**check it here:**
https://jsfiddle.net/wxaw3205/

The same example with more elements:
https://jsfiddle.net/wxaw3205/1/

The last way is using the !important declaration, it provides a way for You to give a CSS value more weight than it naturally has.
For the last example, lets assume that we have the same html markup of the example above, which will be the color now?

```
.one .two .three {
    color: red;
}

.two .three {
    color: blue;
}

.one .three {
    color: green !important;
}
```

**Answer:** green.
Link to live example: https://jsfiddle.net/wxaw3205/2/

And just a little tip: never style the element using the `style=""` attribute, unless you have too! and either the !important.
Most of the time when you have to use them its because you'r stylesheet needs to be reordered.

That's all, I hope it helped you understand.